# website with c++ backend on Windows server

Tags: c++, client-server, backend, web-development-server

**Background:** I have developed a c++ program in Visual Studio which takes a image as input, do some computer vision analysis and then create some results in txt files. Right now I am developing a website as a GUI for the c++ program. So the website will allow user to upload the image to and retrieve the analysis result from the server. And I have already finished the web programming part with wamp in my desktop.

The only problem now is the communication between the frontend website and the c++ program in the backend. I have never worked with server-client system before, so here are my questions:

1. How do I set up the communication framework between my website and c++ program? How does the website sends a message to c++ when the image has been uploaded and tells c++ where to look for this image? How does c++ send a message to the website when it has finished running? I don't have much time left for this project, so is there any basic web-c++ communication framework that I can download and develop on it?
2. How does the website check if the c++ program is running without error? How to check the progress in the backend c++ program?
3. If the user of the websites decides to cancel the previous request, how does the website stop the c++ program when it's already running?
4. How does the c++ support multiple request from different users? How does the c++ start another instance of the program and run on a different request?

Sorry that I am new to this area. Would really appreciate if someone can answer my questions!

Comment: Windows server has a backend of C# as a ASP.NET technology. What you might do is either implement your logic in C#, or find a way to interact with C++ through C#.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) (pronounced "witty", short for web toolkit.) it might provide more than what you want (it also does the web programming for you, but you can link css into it.) but it seems to be around what you want.

I have no personal experience with Wt, but I have tested it and it seems to work very well.

As far as I know, it uses boost.asio as the backend port framework, which might be a place to start if you would like to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

The common practice is C++/CLI wrapper for a native code. You need to design an API for your code and it will be available for using in .NET applications including ASP.NET.